# I am trying to return all lists from SharePoint site using CSOM, but my query only returns back 1 item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, csom, modern-experience

I'm new to the share point API. I am attempting to retrieve all the lists in a SharePoint subsite so that later I can choose one of the document libraries and upload a file.

When the query finishes it only returns a single list item, named "User Information List" when I expected there to be 6 in total including a "Shared Documents" document library. The code I'm using is below:

[image]

For authentication I am following the Microsoft [modern authentication standard from https://docs.microsoft.com/](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard)

It seems like it should be pretty simple and I am just missing something small.

If anyone could help me understand why I am not returning the data back from the SP client as expected it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try example given in Microsoft docs at: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#retrieve-all-sharepoint-lists-in-a-website) & let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap  I tried the example in the link. I get the same results back 1 list comes back titled "User Information List".

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?